# Wendel Theorem for center of group algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $G$ be a locally compact SIN-group. Then $ZL^{1}(G)$ has a bounded approximate identity. I want to prove that the multiplier algebra of $ZL^{1}(G)$ is equal to $ZM(G)$ (center of measure algebra). If $(e_{\alpha})$ is a central approximate identity for $ZL^{1}(G)$ and T is a multiplier of $ZL^{1}(G)$ then $T\in B(ZL^{1}(G))$. I want to know whether $T(e_{\alpha})$ must be an element of $ZM(G)$.

Comment: I understand your first question, but not your last comment. $T(e_\alpha)\in ZL^1(G)$ because, _by definition_, $T$ maps elements of $ZL^1(G)$ to elements of $ZL^1(G)$.

Comment: Have you succeeded in proving this when $G$ is a compact group?

Answer (score 2):

This is a proof for $G$ a compact group.

Define $ZC(G)=\{ f\in C_b(G): f(xyx^{-1})=f(y) \ \forall x,y \in G\}$.
To prove the fact that $ZM(G)$ is the multiplier algebra of $ZL^1(G)$, first we need the following lemma.

**Lemma 1.**
Let $G$ be a compact group. Then $ZM(G)$ is the dual of $ZC(G)$.

*Proof.* Let us define a norm decreasing  map  $P: C(G) \rightarrow ZC(G)$ by 
$$
P(f)(x)=\int_{G} f(yxy^{-1}) dy.
$$
Hence, $P^*:ZC(G)^* \rightarrow M(G)$, the adjoint of $P$, is a norm decreasing map.

Let $\iota: ZC(G) \rightarrow C(G)$ be the canonical embedding which takes every function to itself. Then $\iota^*: M(G) \rightarrow ZC(G)^*$. Let us define $j:=\iota^*|_{ZM(G)}$ which is still a norm decreasing map. We claim that $P^*\circ j$ is the identity map. To prove this, first note that for each $f\in C(G)$, $\iota\circ P(f)=P(f)$. Therefore, for each $\mu \in ZM(G)$, we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle P^*\circ j(\mu), f\rangle &=& \langle j(\mu), P(f)\rangle \\
&=& \langle \mu, \iota\circ P(f)\rangle\\
&=& \langle \mu, P(f)\rangle\\
&=& \int_G P(f)(x) d\mu(x)\\
&=& \int_{G\times G} f(yxy^{-1}) dy d\mu(x)\\
&=& \int_{G} \int_{G} f(y) d(\delta_x*\mu * \delta_{x^{-1}})(y) dx\\
&=& \int_G f(y) d\mu(y).
\end{eqnarray*}
$\Box$

Now we can prove the main result:

*Proof of the result.* First note that for each $\mu \in ZM(G)$, $\mu \in M(ZL^1(G))$ because  on one hand $\mu *f \in ZM(G)$ for every $f\in ZL^1(G)$ and on the other hand, $L^1(G)$ is an ideal in $M(G)$.

Conversely, let $(e_\alpha)$ be a central bounded approximate identity of $L^1(G)$.
For each $T\in M(ZL^1(G))$, $(T(e_\alpha))$ is a bounded net in $ZM(G)$. So weakly$^*$ it approaches some $\mu \in ZM(G)$. Hence,  for each $f\in ZL^1(G)$,
$$
T(f)= w^*-\lim_\alpha T(e_\alpha * f)= w^*-\lim_\alpha T(e_\alpha)* f = \mu*f.
$$

$\Box$

**Note.** For a general locally compact group $G$, $ZL^1(G)$ always has a bounded approximate identity (by J. LIUKKONEN and A. MOSAK, *HARMONIC ANALYSIS AND CENTERS OF GROUP ALGEBRAS*, *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc*, 1974).

Comment: Of course when $G$ is not compact $M(G)$ is not the dual of $C_b(G)$. So I'm not sure what you are doing in the noncompact case